# Как отлаживать регулярки в nginx.conf?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

У меня возникла проблема с регулярками в nginx.conf. Я прописал такую переадресацию:

```
location /static/ {
        rewrite ^\/static\/version-(\w+)\/(.*)$ /static/$2 permanent;
}
```

Протестировал её на адресе /static/version-1/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js и убедился, что всё корректно: сервер переадресовал меня на /static/js/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js.

Но уже в процессе работы обнаружилось, что на адресе /static/version-1/css/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff переадресация не срабатывает (т.е. сервер возвращает ошибку 404, хотя по адресу /static/css/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff корректно отдаёт файл).

В связи с этим прошу подсказки: как можно продебажить понимание сервером регулярных выражений? Могу ли я как-то увидеть, как nginx распарсил адрес? Есть ли в nginx какой-то debug mode?

Comment: Регулярка она и в nginx регулярка. Покажите весь серверный конфиг